# Add answered-novotes CSS class to answers column

Tags: feature-request, answers, design, question-lists

When I scan the front page of Stack Overflow, I habitually look for non-green boxes for opportunities to answer questions. Would it be helpful to differentiate between questions that have answers with at least one upvote, and questions that have answers, but none of those answers have an  upvote? I know for myself, I'd like to style my answered-novotes similarly to the unanswered CSS style, so that I'm more likely to consider those questions as needing help. Thoughts?

[image: Stack Overflow’s question list showing the different styles and corresponding HTML classes for the box that shows how many answers a question has; followed by OP’s suggestion.]

EDIT: Super User has a similar non-boxed style for questions with answers but no accepted answers. This request is taking that one step further you could say

Comment: Have you seen [the unanswered pages](http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/?tab=newest)? Already filtered to exclude questions with up-voted answers.

Comment: yup i use that too. except the my tags sub-tab never changes b/c it's sorted by votes. and the newest sub-tab includes tags I don't care about. I like the front page interesting tab b/c it's my tags AND sorted by recent