# Different formatting in question lists for questions that count as unanswered

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add answered-novotes CSS class to answers column](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91651/add-answered-novotes-css-class-to-answers-column)

When looking through the list of questions, I tend to want to help those that are unanswered.

For example, browsing the [list of questions tagged <kbd>Office Interop</kbd>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/office-interop), you have three differing formats - no answers, some answers and some answers with one accepted. It is not obvious that my question there is technically unanswered, as it says there is a single answer, with a big green friendly background, which appeals to my subconscious to say "don't worry about this question, it's all good now"

I feel that there would be benefit in splitting the formatting for "some answers" to be "some answers, with no votes" (i.e. counted as unanswered) and "some answers with at least one with a positive score" (i.e. counted as answered) - this could then be combined with the existing sort order tabs and be a bit more useful than the current view.